# htaccess for silex installed not at root

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, silex

This is my folder structure

```
localhost/
    mysilex/
        .htaccess (removes 'public')
        vendor/
        public/
            index.php
            .htaccess (forward to index.php)
```

Content of `mysilex/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Content of `mysilex/public/.htaccess`

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

If I use this route

```
$app->get('/mysilex/', function(){
    return "Hello world";
});
```

It worked when I open up

```
http://localhost/mysilex/
```

But I wanted to be able to use this route in my app

```
$app->get('/', function(){
    return "Hello world";
});
```

What changes I need to make in the `.htaccess`?

I have tried using `RewriteBase /mysilex/` but it doesn't worked.

PS. I'm not using any `vhost`

Comment: Just a hunch, but shouldn't you move the .htaccess on ```mysilex/``` folder one level up and change the ```RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]``` to ```RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysilex/public/$1 [L]```

Comment: Oh, and following best practices you should change your web server configuration in order to point your public web folder to the public folder on of your project, otherwise anyone could access any file.